# Ambient Occlusion node in EEVEE not working

Tags: rendering, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

So I am using Blender 2.8, and I cannot seem to get the Ambient Occlusion node to work in EEVEE. I realize it is in beta, so it could just be a bug in 2.8, but I have seen other people use ambient occlusion in eevee ([like here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB7l_IUcQn4)), so that leads me to believe it is not an issue with 2.8.

Below is a model with an ambient occlusion shader attached in Cycles, and it works as expected:
[image: in Cylces]

However, when I use the same setup in EEVEE, it doesn't work, and the ambient occlusion node outputs the same color across the entire model, making it show up as completely flat:
[image: broken one in EEVEE]

Is there something I am doing wrong with the ambient occlusion node to cause this to happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to enable AO in Eevee render settings. See the render tab in your second screenshot.

Comment: Oh thanks, that was dumb of me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @sacrish said, I had just forgotten to enable Ambient Occlusion in the render settings, causing it to not work.